# VB Script for Windows Servers

Tags: windows, vbscript, patch-management

I require a VB script which when run gives me the details about the latest Windows patch that was updated on the servers along with the date & time.

Comment: Have you considered using [WSUS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/wsus/default) instead of doing this manually?

Comment: Anu- I hope that you're not asking anyone on this site to write one for you, or search Google for you? You haven't told us what you've tried so far and what did or didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the following command:

```
wmic /node:"<servername>" qfe get description,fixComments,hotfixid,installedby,installedon,servicepackineffect
```

Where  is the hostname of your server.

You might want to take a look at WSUS.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea but you could try something like this

http://forums.eeye.com/index.php?/topic/1883-windows-patch-installation-date/

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: http://technet.microsoft.com/library/ee176545.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Please use powershell for new / future scripting on windows platform.  it is the modern oo based shell environment and should meet your needs.  VBS is a pre 2000 (over 10 years old) scripting solution that should be on the retirement technology list.

This blog post has lots of interesting info regarding your need:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/08/13/use-powershell-to-audit-and-install-windows-patches.aspx

There are several sites that contain pre-built powershell scripts you can bing / google for.

Adding: Agree with other commentors that WSUS is a good solution for this as well.